# deploy:deploy-file not finding artifact, group, etc. from pom file

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

According to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html), `deploy:deploy-file` is supposed to work when you specify a pom file directly; in that case, the documentation says you don't need "groupId, artifactId, version and packaging arguments ... because deploy-file goal will get these information from the given POM".

However, when I run the following command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=webapp-6.0.2.pom -Dfile=webapp-6.0.2.jar -DrepositoryId=internal -Durl=dav:http://server:9091/archiva/repository/internal -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false
```

I get this error:

```
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [deploy:deploy-file] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [deploy:deploy-file]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Missing group, artifact, version, or packaging information
```

Using `mvn -e -X` doesn't reveal any additional insight. I am using Maven 2.0.9 and maven-deploy-plugin version 2.3.

Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Based on what you have mentioned i would suggest to use the most up-to-date version of maven-deploy-plugin which is 2.8.1 and **not 2.3**. And most important is to use Maven 3.X cause Maven 2.0.9 is too old furthermore 2.0.9 is not the most-up-date (if we really can speak of this) version of Maven 2.0. Maven 2.0.9 is from 2008 which mean 5 years old. Update to Maven 3.1.1 or Maven 3.2.1...

Comment: Upgrading is not an option for me right now, but yes, it appears the [newest version](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-deploy-plugin-2.8.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/deploy/DeployFileMojo.java?view=markup) is working the way the documentation describes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: the deploy-file mojo doesn't inherit the version number from the parent project, so it must be in the pom directly or specified as `-Dversion=...` parameter.

Depending on how you look at it, this is either a bug or a lack in the documentation. The source for the deploy plugin has:

```
Parent parent = model.getParent();

if ( this.groupId == null )
{
    if ( parent != null && parent.getGroupId() != null )
    {
        this.groupId = parent.getGroupId();
    }
    if ( model.getGroupId() != null )
    {
        this.groupId = model.getGroupId();
    }
}
if ( this.artifactId == null && model.getArtifactId() != null )
{
    this.artifactId = model.getArtifactId();
}
if ( this.version == null && model.getVersion() != null )
{
    this.version = model.getVersion();
}
if ( this.packaging == null && model.getPackaging() != null )
{
    this.packaging = model.getPackaging();
}
```

This means that the plugin only attempts to inherit the `groupId` from the parent, but not the version number. In my particular case, my pom was missing the `version` and I was expected it to be inherited from the parent, like most of the rest of maven does.